# Proper way to pop from a react component's array-type state attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have an react component like:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            myStack: []
        };
    },

    ...

    pop: function(a) {
        // any concise , elegant way to pop from array type state?
    }
}
```

Maybe I could just write

```
pop: function() {
    var clone = _.clone(this.state.myStack);
    clone.pop();
    this.setState({myStack: clone});
}
```

But it looks ugly... I know it works but just looking at the code itself becomes annoying when I write these codes.

Is there any nice way for popping from an array type react component state?

I implemented `push()` like

```
push: function(a) {
    this.setState({myStack: this.state.myStack.concat([a])});
}
```

in a single line.

I believe there is an nice one line solution for `pop`, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
pop: function() {
  this.setState({
    myStack: this.state.myStack.slice(0, -1)
  });
}
```